# (Blender 2.81) Marking or clearing seam causes mesh to unwrap. Live unwrap is OFF

Tags: uv

As I said, Live unwrap (under UV editor - UV tab - live unwrap) is OFF. Despite that, either clearing or marking seams causes my mesh to instantly re-unwrap. What could be the cause of this?